# Should I send JS exceptions manually to Google Analytics?

Tags: javascript, angular, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am new to Google Analytics. I have an Angular 4 application. I would like to know when an uncaught JavaScript exception had been thrown. I've set up a Google Analytics via Google Tag Manager. It works perfectly for history change event (navigation between Angular routes). But it doesn't fire JS errors.[image]

And here is what I see in debug pane:

[image]

You can see an exception in console but JS Error tag is not fired. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here is what I found. You shouldn't expect that exceptions will be fired automatically. You should implement ErrorHandler and manually throw event from there.

```
import {ErrorHandler, Injector} from '@angular/core';
import {Angulartics2GoogleTagManager} from 'angulartics2/gtm';

export class MyErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {

  private analytics: Angulartics2GoogleTagManager;

  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
  }

  handleError(error: Error) {
    console.error(error);

    if (!this.analytics) {
      this.analytics = this.injector.get(Angulartics2GoogleTagManager);
    }

    this.analytics.eventTrack(JSON.stringify(error.message), {
      event: 'jsError',
      label: JSON.stringify(error.stack).replace('\n', ' ')
    });

  }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```
{provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: MyErrorHandler, deps: [Injector]},
```